# There is no parameter $1 ...Sending SQL statement to Rails for Postgresql, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
          "WITH numberofdays AS 
          (SELECT percent_change FROM asset_histories 
          WHERE date < $1
          AND asset_symbol = $2
          ORDER BY date DESC
          LIMIT $3)
          SELECT stddev_samp(percent_change) as stdev FROM numberofdays",
          [day,symbol,daystolimit])
```

Where day, symbol and daystolimit are variables assigned before the above code. They are assigned as such:

```
day = '2013-03-25'
symbol = 'AAPL'
daystolimit = 20
```

I don't want to use `#{variable}` because of the potential for malicious intent. 
As referenced in the title, my statement is returning

`PGError ERROR: there is no parameter $1 LINE 1 ... WHERE date <$1 AND...`

Using Postgresql 9.2 and rails 3.2

EDIT adding alternative solution I found here:

In addition to mu is too short where he uses connection.method(:quote), I couldn't find documentation on it so I came across another post where quoting was done as such:

```
a = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
a.execute(%Q{SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = #{a.quote(variable)}...})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fine (?) manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQLAdapter.html#method-i-execute):

> **execute(sql, name = nil)**
>
> Executes an SQL statement, returning a PGresult object on success or raising a PGError exception otherwise.

Note that the second parameter isn't for binding parameters, it is a name for (AFAIK) logging purposes.

ActiveRecord doesn't actually use bound parameters internally, it just does the quoting and escaping itself and builds a big SQL string for the database (*cringe*). You can mimic this behavior using the `quote` method and string interpolation:

```
q = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.method(:quote)
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(%Q{
    WITH numberofdays AS 
    (SELECT percent_change FROM asset_histories 
    WHERE date < #{q[day]}
    AND asset_symbol = #{q[symbol]}
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT #{daystolimit})
    SELECT stddev_samp(percent_change) as stdev FROM numberofdays
})
```

You'll have to ensure that `daystolimit` is a number on your own (or quote it too and cast to an integer inside the SQL).

Alternatively, connect to the database using the [raw pg](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/frames) interface and use real prepared statments.

Comment: Ty, I saw others referencing that method as a way to pass parameters here and there and thought it was the correct way. I will look into the quote method more.

Comment: @Chowza: Numbered placeholders (`$1`, `$2`, ...) are the preferred way to use placeholders with PostgreSQL, the problem is that `execute` doesn't understand them so you have to do it by hand. If you talk to PostgreSQL through the low level `pg` interface, then you can use numbered placeholders. I don't know how to get the underlying PostgreSQL connection out of ActiveRecord though.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't gotten to the level where I need to learn pg yet so I'm gonna keep everything high level :) By the way, the quotes should be in square brackets like such: `#{q[symbol]}`. Had to play around with it to figure that out. Thanks for the help and clarification!

Comment: Also, I couldn't find documentation on `connection.method(:quote)` when trying to figure out the square brackets thing, and I came across `connection.quote`. I'm assuming there is no difference between the two? Would you know? Is there a best practice to use one over the other?

Comment: @Chowza: Thanks for spotting the bracket problem, thinking in the wrong language again :) The `connection.method(:quote)` trick just grabs a short reference to the `quote` method of `connection`, that way we don't have to a bunch of noise inside the SQL. See the [`method` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-method) for details. So my `q` and `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote` are the same thing but `q` is less noisy.

Comment: Wouldn't that fail if any field ends with a backslash?

Comment: @IslamAzab Do you have an example where it does fail?

Comment: Not in this particular scenario, but try this `select 'test \'::tsvector;` or `select E'test\';`